# Autorun an HTML file from a DVD disc

Tags: windows-explorer, internet, autorun

I need to autorun an HTML file in Internet Explorer (only) from a DVD disc.

The file is in the root of the disc.

How can I achieve this?

This is the `autorun.inf` file:

```
[autorun]
open=iexpore -k index.html
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to make an auto run inf file that execute Iexplorer but i can't open the html file neither without using a full path. This will be used with a content DVD so must work independently from the drive letter the OS assigned when mounting.

Comment: Edit your question and show us your inf file. The more you give us, the more people can try to figure out what you're trying to do, and how to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Did you copy and paste directly from the `.inf` file to the question? `iexplore` is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: No i didn't copy. My inf file has the iexplore command but don't work at all